# Grails create table List<String> name

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

Why i can't create table List to my database?

my domain class :

```
class Test {
   List<String> names
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the supported syntax:

```
class Test {
   static hasMany = [names: String]
}
```

Comment: Hi Burt, thanks for your answer, but can you show me another way to save List<String> without hasMany, thanks

Comment: It depends on how you want the data to be stored in the database. Work backwards from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the way exposed in the question and it's working.

```
class Test {
   List<String> names
}
```

This generates a table called: `test_names` with columns `test_names_id, names_ids, names_ids_idx`.

Comment: Did someone know how to paginate this names field?