# Grails - List of Long not getting saved

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class similar to the following:

```
class Record {

  Long id

  List numbers = []

  String description

  void recordNumber(Long number) {
    //requirements, validations, etc.
    numbers << number
  }

}
```

Then I defined a Web service similar to the code below:

```
class RecordController extends RestfulController {

  def recordNumber(Record record) {
    def number = getNumberFromRequest() //request.JSON, request.XML, etc.
    if (record) {
      record.recordNumber(number)
      record.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
  }

}
```

However, the numbers on the list don't seem to get saved, because when I retrieve a `Record`, the list empty. I have test for the code and it seems ok. Could it also be that the list is lazily loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on [this answer from a previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15170703/404604), I updated the code as follows:

```
class Record {

  static hasMany = [numbers: Long]

  Long id

  String description

  void recordNumber(Long number) {
    //requirements, validations, etc.
    addToNumbers number
  }

}
```

It would seem that if a collection is meant to be persistent, it has to be declared this way, or be mapped in some other methods; I'm just not sure what those other methods are.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving a new `record` instance each time the action is called. You should load it out of the DB instead:

```
def recordNumber( Long id ){
  def record = Record.get id
  def number = getNumberFromRequest() //request.JSON, request.XML, etc.
  //....
}
```

Comment: Based on how I understand the the official docs, `RestfulController` automatically retrieves the instance of associated domain class when you set it as a parameter; that seems to work for my unit tests. The code that retrieves the record (GET) uses the same pattern, and I get one with correct id but empty list. Anyway, I'll try doing this and see if it works.

Comment: I looked in my code, and I'm actually using this to update and not `recordNumber(Record record)`, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: print out the `record.errors` to see the possible problem

Comment: do you really need a `List`? As far as I can remember, the list's entries must be refreshed upon each save, to update the list-index column. Try using `Set` if it's not an issue for you.

Comment: I changed the collection type to `Set` and I'm still getting the same problem.